# Atom in Radiation Reservoir (Cohen-Tannoudji formalism)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, quantum-statistics, atomic-clocks

My task is to generalize the description in Cohen-Tannoudji's "Atom-Photon Interaction", p.284 from dipole only case onto forbidden transitions getting analogues of E.11 and E.13.

Attempt:

1. Took equation for interaction term as $V(\pmb r)=\pmb p \cdot \pmb A(\pmb r)$
2. Rewrote as $V(\pmb r) = \sum_{\lambda}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi \hbar c^2}{\omega_{\lambda}L^3}}(\pmb p \cdot \hat{e}_{\lambda})\hat{a} e^{i\pmb k_{\lambda} \cdot \pmb{r}}$ where $\pmb{r}$ is the radius-vector of the excited electron in the atom's COM reference frame
3. Plugged in E.11 and E.13 and got almost the same equations, e.g.

$\Gamma_{a \rightarrow b} \propto \frac{2\pi}{\hbar}\sum_{\lambda} \langle n_i \rangle |\langle b; 0_i |(\pmb{p}\cdot \hat{e}_{\lambda})e^{i\pmb k_{\lambda} \cdot \pmb{r}}|a;1_i\rangle|^2 \delta (\hbar \omega_i - \hbar \omega_f)$

From this one can see that the presence of higher order contributions should not change the photon population in the reservoir, only photon coupling to the atom's energy levels. Coupling terms are known from conventional quantum mechanics and don't have anything to do with quantum statistics.

Hence, either this task is too simple (it happens), or I am missing something. Please, help!